# What is the full URL to invoke the AWS Eventbridge Scheduler REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduler

I'm trying to invoke the AWS Eventbridge Scheduler, via its REST API, to create a schedule.  In the documentation it just gives the resource and action (POST /schedules/[Schedule Name]).  Does anyone know what the fully qualified URL is that I would need to send an HTTP request?

I've looked all over the place and can't seem to find a reference.  Even though the lambda I want to do this in is written in Python, I can't use a boto client due to the environment (which I have no control over) having a boto3 version a bit behind being able to use the sheduler (and event rules are not an option).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's used like that :

```
https://events.{aws-region}.amazonaws.com/{api-version}/schedules/{schedule-name}
```

{aws-region} is the region where your AWS account is located (example 'us-west-2')

{api-version} is the version of the API you want to use (example: '2015-10-07').

hope this helped you